# make all images in bootstrap col 100% width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

Is there a less synthax that could make images 100% width in bootstrap columns no matter their size ?

I tried

```
.col-* img {
   width: 100%;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ror6k4j9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css-like regex

```
div[class^="col-"] img {
   width: 100%;
}
```

one more thing to try by less is to set regexp as variable:

```
@divcol: div[class^="col-"];

@{divcol} {
    img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Anyway Twitter-bootstrap supports class `img-fluid` with `max-width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` so it's not nessesery to duplicate it.